# AWS Backup - How to get the cluster id value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-sns, aws-backup

Here's the scenario, after AWS Backup completes backup cluster aurora RDS, it will send 1 event message to SNS topic. Finally, I'll use lambda to get cluster information.

AWS Backup job completed -> Event message -> SNS topic -> trigger lambda

The thing is that I cannot find any information related to cluster ID ( tried with EventBridge ). I've tried to use Event Subscription ( RDS), but, it won't send any information while I perform AWS Backup.

Please let me know if you have any other ideas, thanks in advance

Comment: Are you logging the entire `event` object that is passed into Lambda? If so, can you include that log in your question?

Comment: That was the plan.. But I need to try send the event to SNS and then check event via email notification first before go to Lambda step

Comment: So at this point you are only sending the event to SNS? Then post the email content in your question. Please provide all the details you have in your question.

Comment: Okay, I got the information I needed from ResourceArn (SNS event). Here's the output: 

{
 "Type" : "Notification",
 "MessageId" : "3d405e4b-e9cd-5d19-a412-0564d3b5bc41"
 "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:669459364263:notifi-test",
 "Message" : "{
...
\"source\":\"aws.backup\",\"account\":\"******\,\"region\":\"ap-southeast-2\",\"resources\":[\***\"],\"detail\":{\"resourceType\":\"Aurora\",\"resourceArn\":\"arn:aws:rds:ap-southeast-2:669459364263:cluster:***
}

Comment: I'll have to get the cluster id from "ResourceArn: "string" based on (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/backup.html#Backup.Client.describe_backup_job)
Do you have any thoughts?